# How to pass the value to html input by add optional parameters to the link of the website to turn it into an API (flask)

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to flask and I wonder how to pass the value to the HTML  by adding optional parameters into the link

Example HTML:

```
<HTML>
   <body>
       <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
           <input type=text name=link>
           <input type=submit value=Open>
       </form>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

Code I'm using to call the HTML above:

```
@app.route('/link', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def open_link():
   if request.method == "POST":
      if 'link' != '':
         text = request.form['link']

         webbrowser.open(text)

return render_template("get_link.html")
```

Now, I want to add a parameter to the link to automatically pass the value for the input in, so that I can make it into an API

Example

```
http://192.168.5.107:8000/link/**add_para_here = hi**
```

Any suggestion? and only sorry for my bad English.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to use optional url parameters within your request. So that the url can be created in the following way.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/link?param0=value0&param1=1
```

In this case the form would look like this.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('link', param0='value1', param1=1) }}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="link">
  <input type="submit" value="Open">
</form>
```

Within the endpoint, the parameters can be queried via [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args). Default values and an optional type conversion can also be specified here.

```
@app.route('/link', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def open_link():
    param0 = request.args.get('param0')
    param1 = request.args.get('param1', 0, type=int)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'link' != '':
            text = request.form['link']
            # ...
    return render_template("get_link.html")
```

Have fun implementing your project.

Comment: Thank you very much